# Pursue my masters again

Tags: student-visa

I have enrolled for masters in Australia in March 2019. Amid the pandemic in 2020 returned to India for personal issues dropped my masters and working here since then. After three years being in industry and having exposure to IT industry now I’d like to continue my masters again now confused whether I can do masters(cs) in USA (coz of tech) or any where else? A lot of people are scaring me a lot saying you won’t get any student visas. So drop out students re-apply to other countries at all ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you get a visa? I'm not sure I understand the logic, why are these people saying these things to you? What are they basing it on?

Comment: As I didn’t finish my studies in australia they expect me for a strong reason at the time of visa interview. When I say coz of my personal issues they won’t consider it at all

Comment: I don't see why they would care why you dropped out years ago, that's between you and your school. Dropping out is not an immigration offense as long as you didn't overstay your student visa.

Comment: @littleadv It may be an immigration offense if the dropout is not correctly registered with immigration, but provided OP did officially dropout (and not just abandon without telling anyone), this is something for the college to deal with

Comment: @NicolasFormichella I did inform the immigration regarding it and i didn’t overstay beyond my visa. Thank you both for making me understand the situation from different perspective.